# How can I efficiently compute the minimum and maximum value for integral types?

Tags: c

> Exercise 2-1. Write a program to determine the ranges of char, short,
> int, and long variables, both signed and unsigned, by printing
> appropriate values from standard headers and by direct computation.
> Harder if you compute them: determine the ranges of the various
> floating-point types.

I've wrote this code for some of the types:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int u;

        for (u = 1; u > 0; ++u);

        int l = u;
        --u;

        printf("int : %d and %d\n", l, u);

        char u_c;

        for (u_c = 1; u_c > 0; ++u_c);

        char l_c = u_c;
        --u_c;

        printf("char : %d and %d\n", l_c, u_c);

        short u_s;

        for (u_s = 1; u_s > 0; ++u_s);

        short l_s = u_s;
        --u_s;

        printf("short : %d and %d\n", l_s, u_s);
 
        return 0;
}
```

The problem is that for large types like int, it takes close to 5 or 6 seconds for the for loop to end, is there a better and efficient way to this or ...?

Comment: FYI, this is a bad exercise because “computing” the range is not entirely possible in strictly conforming C. It is possible to determine whether two’s complement, one’s complement, or sign-and-magnitude is used, and then it is possible to determine the minimums and maximums used via bitwise operations provided there are no trap representations. If there are trap representations, the ranges cannot be fully tested without implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: The "appropriate values from standard headers" would require `#include <limits.h>` and `#include <float.h>` and then perhaps `printf("int %d to %d\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);` and `printf("float %f to %f\n", -FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX);` etc.

Comment: Did you already try writing the "printing appropriate values from standard headers" version?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> The problem is that for large types like int, it takes close to 5 or 6 seconds for the for loop to end, is there a better and efficient way to this or ...?

Well, for `int` you are counting up to 2,147,483,647 times.  This is two billion increment operations, and getting those finished in 5-6sec is a good hit!!!

There's no better way to count to 2^31 - 1 than just do the counting.  But this is only if you want to get the highest value **by counting.**  Just continue reading.

### First a note:

Signed overflow (this has already been noted in some of the other answers) means undefined behaviour.  (The approach for `signed` and `unsigned` described below, will probably apply even is you, at some point, get an U.B.)  This was not that way at the time K&R was written, even in its second edition, which covered the first ANSI-C specs available.  Once given that, we can pursue the target of calculating the maximum and minimum values using two approaches:

1. Using some given architecture.  At the time of K&R writing the most common architecture with C compilers available was the DEC PDP-11 (in several sizes and flavors) which supported 16bit two's complement arithmetic.
2. Stay with the actual standards and handle U.B. properly.
   Both approaches have problems that will make you impossible to determine the maximum/minimum values of some of the types available in todays computer.

I'll try to give you something which, to my opinion, will allow you to get something usable in most of the cases.

### One possible way

If you want to get the maximum value of an integer calculating it... you can start with 1 (or -1), and double it, until you get a number that is not larger (or lesser, for negatives) than the previous number.  This will mean that you have crossed the boundary line of UB.  It is expected that, as you approach either side, you will have a strictly growing/decreasing sequence, giving you numbers that fit in the type, until you cross the border.  In that case, the previous number will be one such candidate to be the target (not finished yet).  A better approach than the one you followed, incrementing the numbers until you get the final target is by doubling them, as you take only 32 times to overflow a 32bit number and 128 loops for a 128bit number.  An multiplication by 2 will do the trick, for both, positive and negative numbers (everywhere in the book, both kinds of bitlogic and arithmetic, indicating that K&R assumes implicitly that two's complement is in use, I have specifically edited this answer to never include bit logical operators, so no dependency on the bit representation of number is included --even you can use a different multiplication factor than 2, e.g. 10, but this will slow things a bit)

Once you get a number that is not larger than the previous one (of course, the maximum number cannot be further doubled or that new number would be the maximum, so I can perfectly assume as a good approach that even in the case of U.B. (this is because we work with the previous number to U.B. and never with the result of the overflow)  we will not get a U.B. condition and at the same time got a larger number)  Multiplying by two can give you a final target (remember, the target is the previous to U.B.) now you can save a copy of your number and try to add, each time a value that is divided by the same number (2 in this case) as it was multiplied before, and that number added to the target obtained value to see if we get a new target larger than the one you had before (we always maintain the latest valid target, which will be the requested maximum/minimum).  After you divide that number by 2 enough times to 1 (remember that the number is always a power of 2, so it's always divisible by 2, until you get the final 1)  You will get a number that is larger, and generates an overflow when just added 1, so that will be the maximum value usable in your implementation.

Where should this algorithm fail? Well, in cases in which the program is in an unknown state (e.g. an exception was raised) after the overflow has occurred will make the algorithm fail after the first U.B.  but otherwise, all the calculations will have been used with correct and fine values and it requires to double numbers a top of 30 times in the growing case and another maximum of 29 adds for 32bit signed numbers.

#### Margin note

Based on the availability of resources stated in the original exercise as published in K&R (any edition, as 2nd edition only incorporates ANSI-C extensions to the language, but the text and exercises remain the same), assumed the given context (no access to `<limits.h>` for constants like `INT_MAX` and the like).

Answer (score 3):

**Undefined behavior**

`for (u = 1; u > 0; ++u);` eventually overflows and that is **undefined behavior** (UB) and is not a reliable way to find the limits of a *signed* integer type.

---

Finding limits of an *unsigned* type is easy. Assigning -1 to the type is a quick solution - and well defined.  Assigning an out-of-range value to a *unsigned* type "wraps" around.

**Assuming** the  *signed integer* type and its corresponding *unsigned* type have the same number of value + sign bits  (or equivalently the same number of padding bits) and that the *signed integer* encodes using 2's complement (required with C23), the max value of the *signed* type is about half the *unsigned* one.

`short` and `long` follow likewise.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calculate_integer_type_range(void) {
  unsigned char uc = (unsigned char) -1;
  printf("unsigned char       0 to %hhu\n", uc);
  unsigned u = (unsigned) -1;
  printf("unsigned            0 to %u\n", u);
  unsigned long long ull = (unsigned long long) -1;
  printf("unsigned long long  0 to %llu\n", ull);

  printf("\nAssuming: 2's complement and no padding.\n\n");

  signed char sc = (signed char) (uc/2);
  printf("signed char         %hhd to %hhd\n", -sc - 1, sc);
  int i = (int) (u/2);
  printf("int                 %d to %d\n", -i - 1, i);
  long long ll = (long long) (ull/2);
  printf("long long           %lld to %lld\n", -ll - 1, ll);

  // char is a little tricky as we first need to determine if it is signed.
  if ((char)-1 < 0) {
    char c = (char) (uc/2);
    printf("char                %hhd to %hhd\n", -c - 1, c);
  } else {
    char c = (char) -1;
    printf("char              0 to %hhu\n", c);
  }
}
```

Output

```
unsigned char       0 to 255
unsigned            0 to 4294967295
unsigned long long  0 to 18446744073709551615

Assuming: 2's complement and no padding.

signed char         -128 to 127
int                 -2147483648 to 2147483647
long long           -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
char                -128 to 127
```

Comment: Hmm, having an U.B. doesn't necesarily mean you cannot guess a solution (at least in most of the cases, just look at my answer)  Clearly the context of the problem is not the context and assumptions used today.  Don't act as a Jerusalem christian crusader if you are against killing people.  The exercise would have been banned with today's criteria, but was well suited when the most common architecture for running a C compiler was a PDP-11.

Comment: @LuisColorado The UB of `int u; for (u = 1; u > 0; ++u);` is a modern issue as compilers take advantage to emit optimized code.  It deserves a UB caution more than encouraging a guess of UB outcome.

Comment: @LuisColorado Rather than counts or shifts with its UB, we could take advantage of the C spec with `INT_MAX <= UINT_MAX`, `UINT_MAX` is easy to form, unions, `INT_MAX` is defined in such a way to be a [Mersenne Number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html), `CHAR_BITS`, ....  Instead of dismissing the exercise as belonging in another era, I would rather look at it afresh and try to form an answer based on the C spec.  Given a bit more time, we could focus on a C23 answer.

Comment: Chux, you are probably right, but the exercise states not to use but the type considered, not to use limits constant (so neither `INT_MAX` is available, nor `UINT_MAX` is)  but calculate it.  If you don't have constants and can only do operations, either only arithmetic (I've modified my answer to use only arithmetic, so no internal representation assumption is made) then you sooner or later have to enter into the U.B. domain.  That's precisely the flag that marks you to have reached the limit.  But you can still go safe, if you accept some extra specs, to avoid using the results when (cont.)

Comment: .... you know that U.B. has happened.  Only in the case that the architecture explodes raising an exception, is when you will not be able to calculate the true bounds.  Anyway the question asks for a more efficient way, and I described some algorithm that just doubles the number, instead of incrementing.

Comment: @LuisColorado I do not see support for "not to use but the type considered,"   Question does have " determine the ranges of char, short, int, and long".

Answer (score 0):

Left-shifts or multiplying by 2 would be much faster.  For example, your upper range would be:

```
for (u = 1; u > 0; u <<= 1);
u--;
```

See: https://onlinegdb.com/m9q3Xao1y

Note, signed overflow is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to avoid all loops and just use a few bit/math operations. This assumes an understanding of how [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) numbers are stored:

```
// set all bits
unsigned char v = ~0;

// strip off the most significant bit
char max = v >> 1;

// wrap around
char min = max + 1;

printf("%d == %d\n", min, max);
```

Comment: C, particularly in the age of Kernighan and Ritchie, did not require two’s complement representations. And, even when two’s complement was used, the behavior of shifting a negative value right is implementation-defined. The behavior of `char min = max + 1;`, given that `max` is `CHAR_MAX`, is also implementation-defined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, at the time of K&R time the  most frequent implementation was the DEC PDP-11 (well, others were working about) which had two's complement arithmethic implementation.  IMHO, two's complement can be assumed, while not related to the problem.  UB can be also assumed if you do the trick of considering that on left shifting you should always get a number larger than the one you had.  Based upon this, you can run the left shift algorithm described in my answer, until you get a number that is not larger (U.B happened) but this doesn't affect the previous, and allows you to stop ther

Answer (score 0):

`#include <limits.h>` is the correct answer.

Otherwise, you can manually generate the same constants at compile-time with zero overhead, given some assumptions:

- The code runs on a useful, real-world computer.
- Useful, real-world computers are those which use 2's complement, 8 bit bytes and no padding or trap representations.
- Unsigned to signed conversion does not produce unexpected behavior such as signals getting raised.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int int_max = ( 1u << (sizeof(int)*8 - 1) ) - 1;
  printf("%d\n", int_max);
  int int_min = ( 1u << (sizeof(int)*8 - 1) );
  printf("%d\n", int_min);

  short short_max = ( 1u << (sizeof(short)*8 - 1) ) - 1;
  printf("%hd\n", short_max);
  short short_min = ( 1u << (sizeof(short)*8 - 1) );
  printf("%hd\n", short_min);

  long long_max = ( 1ul << (sizeof(long)*8 - 1) ) - 1;
  printf("%ld\n", long_max);
  long long_min = ( 1ul << (sizeof(long)*8 - 1) );
  printf("%ld\n", long_min);
}
```

Explanation:
By shifting an unsigned `1u` one less than the total number of bits available in the type, we set the MSB to 1. On 2's complement computers, a number with only MSB set gives the minimum number for the type, once cast to the correct signed type. Similarly, a number with MSB set minus 1 gives the maximum number.

Output on gcc 13.2 x86_64:

```
2147483647
-2147483648
32767
-32768
9223372036854775807
-9223372036854775808
```

The disassembly looks like `mov esi, 2147483647` and so on, everything is pre-calculated at compile-time.

`8` can be swapped with `CHAR_BITS`, but if you have access to limits.h you wouldn't be doing silly stuff like this manually anyway.